# Change data attribute value after delay, not working

Tags: jquery, callback, custom-data-attribute

I have a slideshow with a waitForImages plugin, so I hide the images, and after load they fade in, this slideshow has a auto-play feature on a data attribute called data-cycle-timeout, I have this value on "0" in the HTML markup because I want the slider to start it's auto-play function AFTER the first image has loaded and faded in, so I did a callback trying to change the value of the data attribute, but it's not working, anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

```
<div class="cycle-slideshow" 
data-cycle-fx="fade"
data-cycle-speed="500" 
data-cycle-slides="> div"
data-cycle-timeout="0"
>
<div class="slide"></div>
</div> 

$('.slide').hide().imagesLoaded( { background: true }, function() {
$('.slide').fadeIn(300, function(){
$('.cycle-slideshow').data('cycle-timeout', 100);
});
});
```

Comment: you have invalid markup there.

Comment: I don't really know how to post code correctly here, so the code is just posted into one, if that's what you are referring to, if not, what's invalid?

Comment: try fixing it. its easy.